# Convert Return Value of type Array to Integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How do you convert a return whose value is of an array? The `.to_i` seems not to work in my case (inside of a class):

```
class Scenario
    def initialize
        @text = "Next year I'll be 10, but I'm still 9"
    end

    def xx
        @text.scan(/^[^\d]*(\d+)/) do |x|
            return x.map(&:to_i)
        end
    end

    def yy
        @text.scan(/\d+\Z/) do |y|
            return y.to_i # This gives me an integer
        end
    end
end

s = Scenario.new
a1 = s.xx # Is an Array
a2 = s.yy # Is a Fixnum
```

I only need to peform mathematical methods on the numbers: stripping numbers from a sting and apply maths methods.

The result I want is:

```
a1 - a2 = 9
```

Comment: @sawa It is the class. I have included it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "convert an array to an integer", that makes no sense.

What you're trying to do is convert the first element *in* the array to an integer.

Use `x.first.to_i`.

Comment: Not sure why people are devoting my post when I'm learning ruby and my question makes sense. I know I can't add an array to an int, but I know something is wrong with my method "xx". Your answer opened my eyes more. Thanks!